# warning: [deprecation] <TResult>call(Executor,Callable<TResult>) in Tasks has been deprecated

Tags: java, android, firebase, flutter, android-studio

**I'm getting this error while I was running my app (though my app is running fine) :**

```
C:\Users\dassa\Downloads\flutter_windows_2.2.3-stable\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\firebase_storage-10.2.11\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\firebase\storage\FlutterFirebaseStorageTask.java:198: warning: [deprecation] <TResult>call(Executor,Callable<TResult>) in Tasks has been deprecated
    return Tasks.call(FlutterFirebasePlugin.cachedThreadPool, () -> storageTask.cancel());
                ^   where TResult is a type-variable:
    TResult extends Object declared in method <TResult>call(Executor,Callable<TResult>) 20 warnings
```

It would be great if anyone can help me to fix this.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Luckily this is not an error, but just a warning.

It is a known Firebase Flutter SDK issue, and you can track its status on [this github issue](https://github.com/firebase/flutterfire/issues/8375).

We should expect a new release in which this problem will be resolved, soon.

Answer (score -1):

just change the classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.x.x' to classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.10'
[image]